# datetime query of particular hours for entire year

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Row</th><th>Identifier</th><th>date_time</th><th>HvacMode</th><th>CalendarEvent</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>a578bb21941003e7a58a399375b20f274fab5233</td><td>2020-10-31 14:50:00 UTC</td><td>heat</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>683227685eb44f9d231d511e8ae5255ecc1b71fb</td><td>2019-08-19 02:00:00 UTC</td><td>cool</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1afd0d7a8408458d39dde687e1218f2948907c4b</td><td>2021-07-19 19:40:00 UTC</td><td>auto</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>607db2c120782353da1539a008956301341d54c9</td><td>2020-08-29 16:50:00 UTC</td><td>cool</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to get the data for a particular time period 7am-7pm (7:00-19:00) for each day of the year. I have a datetime field in the format 2017:01:01 00:00:00 (example). A bit of a newbie here. I know how to extract for a specific date range, but I don't know how to extract for a date range of particular hours. Working with a very large dataset in BigQuery. Any assistance would be helpful. [sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF6BF.png)

Comment: not clear what you need. can you please provide sample of data you have and expected result?!

Comment: I could not get the table format to work, so I added an image in the question above. I only want the data from hours 07:00:00 to 19:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question you are trying to filter each day of data by the 7-7 time period.
Try the example below:

```
with sample_data as (
    SELECT ts FROM UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 hour)) as ts
)

select *
from sample_data
where 
extract(year from ts) = 2021
and extract(hour from ts) between 7 and 19;
```

Using the extract function, you can pull the hour from the timestamp and then filter on a between.  For more information on the extract function refer to the following documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#extract

Comment: better to create a date dimension in sql once and query that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  If you are referring to the CTE, it is an exemplar set of data to test the functionality in an isolated environment.  Based on the question, there should be no need for a date dim in the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

All;

This worked for the data I need. Thank you for your help. The snippet below gives me the  daytime hours for the month of January.

```
select *
from sample_data where extract(hour from date_time) between 7 and 19
AND date_time between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-31 23:59:00';
```